# Is array with one element equal to the element?

Tags: javascript

I am doing some comparisons in JavaScript. I copied over some code like this:

```
if (input.val() != input.data('original') )
    //do stuff
```

I expect I will have to change something, because at this instance `input` was `<select multiple>` with a number of selectable options limited to 1. But it worked without changes.

I checked and it turns out that:

```
13 == [13]  //true
13 === [13]  //false
```

I did not expect that the comparison would unwrap the array.

Is this an intended and documented feature in JavaScript that I can use and rely on? Or does this only work for me because some browser developer decided to make it work?

Comment: See the spec for `==`.  This is one of the many reasons that you should always use `===` instead.

Comment: `parseInt(13,10) === 13` the same for `+[13]`, so coercing that array to a number returns `13`, and comparing non-strict does type coercion

Comment: @SLaks I couldn't find it, `==` is not the most googleable string. Googling `javascript comparison` I couldn't find a resource explicitly stating this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [**loose equality ( == )**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) is used to compare `Object` and `Number`:

> it attempts to convert its object argument to a primitive value, by attempting > to invoke varying sequences of A.toString and A.valueOf methods on A

So what you actually get by doing that:

```
13 == [13]
```

is:

```
13 == ([13].toString().valueOf())
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it depends, if the element is a string or not.

The result with one element is the result of the toString method, which looks like that one element is equal the element. But the result is always a string, whereas the value might not be a string.

Example with array

> ```
>   array  toString value
> -------  -------------- 
>     [1]             '1'
>  [1, 2]           '1,2'
> ```

For the order of evaluation you might have a look at the standard [ECMA 262 Version 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

[Equality `==` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_())

> The equality operator converts the operands if they are **not of the same type**, then applies strict comparison. If **both operands are objects**, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

Comment: So is `==` using `toString` every time? Or in some specific cases?

Comment: no, the order is to check if strict comparison is possible and then check the value of  `toString` method.

Answer (score 0):

That's how javascript works. `5 == '5'` == true. `5 == [5]` is also true.

Look at these examples.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp\

The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return false.

the `==` will convert both values to a similar type and then use the same comparison as `===`
Read more here about how the `==` conversion works and a chart.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: I see nothing regarding `[5]` or the conversions in the resource you linked.

Comment: @Juris I was linking to examples. I explained how type conversions are made using '==' after the link.

Comment: How are `necessary` conversions chosen and which conversion is chosen in different cases? Do you know if that is documented anywhere?

Comment: @Juris check out the link in my answer, I hope that helps a little.